# Average the spacing between vertices

Tags: mesh, topology

I just subdivided a cube and transformed it into a sphere. I now have a decent sphere with roughly uniform vertex spacing.

The only issue is the corners:

[image]

Now I know you can't get perfect spacing mathematically for spheres this way, but "close enough" is what i am aiming for,

Is there a modifier that can calculate an average spacing between all vertices or a group of selected vertices and adjust the spacing so it looks a bit more uniform?

Answer (score 1):

If all you're looking for is a uniform quad sphere:

1. Enable the Community addon "Add Mesh: Extra Objects"
2. Shift+A Mesh>Round Cube
3. Open the options panel and select "Quadsphere" from the Operator Presets drop down

[image: Extra Objects]

[image: Round Cube]

[image: Quadsphere]

Answer (score 0):

"Is there a modifier that can calculate an average spacing between all vertices or a group of selected vertices and adjust the spacing so it looks a bit more uniform?"

Yes. Enter edit mode, Press F3 (search), look up "set edge length". You have plenty of options there, it is very capable and very self explanatory. It's an operator, not a modifier tho.